# Change all strings in list of lists but the last element

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

I am trying to use list comprehension to create a new list of lists of strings in which all strings but the last will be lowercased. This would be the critical line, but it lowercase all strings:

```
[[word.lower() for word in words] for words in lists]
```

If I do this:

```
[[word.lower() for word in words[:-1]] for words in lists]
```

the last element is omitted.

In general, if the list is rather long, is comprehension the best/fastest approach?

Comment: What do you mean by "best"? What alternatives do you have in mind? A comprehension will probably be easier to read and faster than a plain for-loop, if that's what you mean.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply add back the last slice:

```
[[word.lower() for word in words[:-1]] + words[-1:] for words in lists]
```

For example, with

```
lists = [["FOO", "BAR", "BAZ"], ["QUX"], []]
```

the output is:

```
[['foo', 'bar', 'BAZ'], ['QUX'], []]
```

Answer (score 1):

Map str.lower until the penultimate element and unpack the map object in a list inside a comprehension

```py
# map str.lower to every element until the last word
# and unpack it in a list along with the last word
[[*map(str.lower, words[:-1]), words[-1]] for words in lists]
```

If a sub-list can be empty (as in wjandrea's example), then add a conditional check (although this is far less readable and downright bad code)

```py
[[*map(str.lower, words[:-1]), words[-1]] if words else [] for words in lists]
```